# When using chef, In what case one would set attributes in a node itself?

Tags: chef-infra

When configuring a node, I think the good practice is to have attributes specified in recipes, roles, or environments, but not in the node itself. Also in [Chef's attribute precedence manual](https://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#attribute-precedence), it doesn't even include the case for "attribute located in node". But I noticed that there's this option let you edit attributes of a node in Opscode's Web UI. Does anyone have a scenario that you'd set attributes directly in the node? Thanks.

[image: Opscode screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, don't.

Long answer, it is used sometimes either as part of a self-registration system for service discovery or external storage for idempotence checks (common example being storing a randomly generated DB password as a node attribute).

This is very much a mis-feature of Chef and there are murmurs of trying to fix it in a future major version but nothing concrete yet.